# How to Upload Large Video FIle on server?

Tags: android

How to Upload Large Video FIle on server?
I want up to 50 to 60mb video File on Server but I dont know how its possible. I could not Upload up to 15mb video file on server. Please have any solution Then let me know.

public static String postRequestvideo_test(String url, byte[] video,
            byte[] image, List data) {

```
    String result = "";
    Log.i("video_upload", video + "");
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        // StringEntity se;
        // se = new StringEntity(data, HTTP.UTF_8);
        // httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data, "UTF-8"));
        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        mpEntity.addPart("video_thumbnail", new ByteArrayBody(image,
                "imagename" + ".jpeg"));
        mpEntity.addPart("video",
                new ByteArrayBody(video, "hyman" + ".mp4"));

        mpEntity.addPart("user_key", new StringBody("user_key_test"));
        mpEntity.addPart("video_name", new StringBody("video_name_test"));
        mpEntity.addPart("video_duration", new StringBody(
                "video_duration_test"));

        mpEntity.addPart("video_thumbnail_extn", new StringBody(
                "video_thumbnail_extn_test"));
        httpPost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        int timeoutConnection = 90000000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
        int timeoutSocket = 90000000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpClient
                .execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            result = result.trim();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "-333" + e.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific - what issues exactly did you have while uploading?

Comment: i sending video file as byte array,memory error.

Comment: What is the response, how do you do your call? Please give as much details as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// Old Answer, please **CHECK BELOW FOR NEW ANSWER**

The problem you're having is probably trying to load the entire video (or for that matter any large file) in the memory at once, since the app has a **maximum limited memory allowed**, if you exceed that, it will cause the application to crash and give you Out of Memory exception.

What you need to do is open a connection and set it to **"Keep-Alive"**, then open a **FileInputStream** for reading your video, and start reading and sending as chunks (1-4 MB is probably a good size) until all the file bytes are sent. That way you ensure the stream is sending the data while you're not exceeding your allowed memory limit for your app.

// **New Answer**

Please note that the above is an old answer, right now I only use **MultipartEntity** (org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder) and it takes care of any file size on its own.

Comment: Thank you for reply. You r right for that when any large file upload then everybody can facing problems. but now a day, I have found some solution of that and its uses full everybody working with uploading large file. we have done this on divide file of small part like. i have 30mb file and i have chunk the file in small part and upload the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
mpEntity.addPart(Constant.VIDEO, new FileBody(file,
                         "video/mp4"));
```

I just put it and it's done.